# Why is system asking me to authenticate before shutting down?

Tags: 14.04, login, who

I just went to shut down my laptop and it asked me to authenticate before I could reboot.  This has never happened before, so I figured maybe a recent update changed something.  After a quick search, I found that this happens when multiple users are logged in.  ...odd. I'm the only one logged in.  Or am I?

```
nathanbrauer@beast:~$ who --all
           system boot  2015-09-24 13:30
           run-level 2  2015-09-24 13:30
LOGIN      tty4         2015-09-24 13:30              1247 id=4
LOGIN      tty5         2015-09-24 13:30              1251 id=5
LOGIN      tty2         2015-09-24 13:30              1257 id=2
LOGIN      tty3         2015-09-24 13:30              1258 id=3
LOGIN      tty6         2015-09-24 13:30              1261 id=6
LOGIN      tty1         2015-09-24 13:30              1774 id=1
nathanbrauer ? :0           2015-09-24 13:30   ?          1991 (:0)
nathanbrauer + pts/0        2015-09-25 09:35   .          4173 (:0)
           pts/2        2015-09-25 08:40                 0 id=/2    term=0 exit=0
```

One of those logins is the tty7/regular login, the other is the terminal I'm running to open the command.

So, why is shutdown asking for authentication even when I exit all terminals?

Comment: That's generally a symptom of having a daemon that has been started with sudo. To answer your question we'll going to need an output from `ps auxww`.

Comment: Oops. I guess I shouldn't have restarted. *facepalm*

Comment: I think that's probably the answer. After reboot, it was back to normal. I also did a LOT of updates (from 14.04 to 14.04.3), so it's very possible that the updates started a daemon via sudo.

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer If your question is now solved, please consider posting your solution as a short answer and accepting it afterwards to mark the problem as solved and help future readers with similar issues. Thanks!

Comment: @Wolfer - your comment was likely the answer. Why don't you add the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as an answer then:

That's generally a symptom of having a daemon that has been started with `sudo`.